# Hive table is not shown when using Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, rstudio, sparklyr

I am trying to replicate [this tutorial from RStudio website](https://spark.rstudio.com/examples/yarn-cluster-emr/)

When I load the data into Hive, I can run `show tables` or `select count(*) from airlines` at the Hive command line and I will get the correct response. But later in the tutorial, when I install `sparklyr` and use the command below to connect to the data, no tables are shown in the Connections tab of RStudio.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = config, version = '2.4.4')
```

Also, surprisingly, when I run `hive_context(sc) %>% invoke('sql', 'show tables') %>% collect()` I get no tables back; it is as if Spark is connecting to a different instance of Hive.

Case in point, if I run the following command to add a table to the Hive database, it will show on the Connections tab, and it will be listed when I run `show tables` as a SQL command.

```
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, "iris", overwrite = TRUE)
hive_context(sc) %>% invoke('sql', 'show tables') %>% collect()
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  database tableName isTemporary
  <chr>    <chr>     <lgl>      
1 NA       iris      TRUE
```

But when I go to the Hive command line via terminal and run `show tables;` it will not show an iris table.

How can I tell Spark to connect to the "right" instance of Hive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which environment are you using? For sparklyr 1.0.4+ you need to manually set the spark sql catalog implementation if you running on hadoop 2.6x.You could try adding `spark.sql.catalogImplementation: "hive"`.

Your code may end up looking like this:

```
config <- spark_config()
config$spark.sql.catalogImplementation <- "hive"

sc <- spark_cconnect(master="yarn", config=config, version=...)
```